# HTML Auto Appending File Uploads

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to figure out how to allow for multiple file uploads. Currently my javascript code checks for an on change in the file upload and if there is a change where a file has been chosen then the code will append a new file upload.

The issue is that it only works the first time. Does anybody know what's going on?

JS file:

```
<script>
$(".file").change(function() {
    $(".file").each(function( index ) {
        if ($(this).val() != "") {
            console.log("empty");
            $("#fileUpload").after("<input class=\"file\" type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" id=\"file\">");
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<div id="fileUpload" style="display: none;">
    <input class="file" type="file" name="file[]" id="file">
</div>
```

**SOLVED:**

Here is the working version for anybody who stumbles upon this thread:

```
$(document).on("change", ".file", function() {
    if ($(this).val() != "") {
        $("#fileUpload").append("<input class=\"file\" type=\"file\" name=\"file[]\" id=\"file\"><br>");
    }
});
```

Comment: instead of ``\"`` you can just use ``'``

Comment: I know, but I like using double quotes for HTML attributes :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `$(".file").change(function(){` for `$(document).on("change", ".file", function(){`

It happens because your code only runs in already existing elements. With the proposed change it will works

Comment: Thanks, I also had to remove the for loop, but it is working now!